# C# PictureBox.Image Parameter is Invalid

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this issue, I'm assinging an Image in a PictureBox and I added each PictureBox in a list, then I removed each picture box and create a new one and it's working fine the first 50 or 70 times ,  but then I have an error Message that said "Parameter is invalid" when I'm assign the same image from Resource.Properties.

```
stop_disabled.Image = Properties.Resources.stop_disabled; //Parameter is invalid
stop_disabled.SizeMode = stop.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
stop_disabled.Dock = stop.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
stop_disabled.Location = stop.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 177);
stop_disabled.Margin = stop.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
stopButtonList.Add(stop_disabled);
```

Comment: Could you please add more of your code?

Comment: this code is inside in a function and I use



`if (supervisorCameras.Count < 12)
   {
      this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
         {
           GUISupervisor(); //ADD THE GUI IF IT IS LESS THAN 12
         }));
                           
            Supervisor_in_Charge(Parameters[2]);
       } `